# Option to format/indent code in Highlight.js

Tags: highlight.js

How do you make highlight.js auto format the code? Is there an option or function? I am passing in a string like the below:

```
&lt;div&gt; &lt;p&gt; foo &lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
```

And I am trying obtain the following output with the HTML auto-formatted:

```
<div>
  <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

Full code:

```
<pre id="output"><code>  &lt;div&gt; &lt;p&gt; foo &lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt; </code></pre>

<script>hljs.highlightBlock($('#output')[0]);</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  What is your current code not doing for you?  To be clear Highlight.js highlights code it does not "beautify" it or change the spacing, etc...

Answer (score -3):

The highlight.js documentation says you can use the `.value` property to autoformat html.  From [the docs](https://highlightjs.org/usage/):

```js
const highlightedCode = hljs.highlightAuto('<span>Hello World!</span>').value
```

Though this is talking specically about a Node.js environment.  I'm not sure if it will work in a browser environment, you can you try it.  Might also save you the need to use html character references and just use < and > freely in your string.

Comment: highlightAuto is to auto detect the language, not format the output